# Responsive css is not working

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries

I am writing separate separate css for device resolution with

`@media only screen 
  and (min-width: 320px)
  and (max-width: 480px) 
  and (orientation: portrait) {
  // css goes here
}`

and device resolution with

`@media only screen 
  and (min-width: 360px)
  and (max-width: 640px) 
  and (orientation: portrait) {
  // css goes here
}`

But `360px*640(orientation:portrait)` css is not working. its taking default 320px*480px CSS. 
How i write css which work on `360px*640(orientation:portrait)` device.

Comment: Let's see your code then

Comment: please refer this http://stackoverflow.com/a/35605310/5383669

Comment: use !important on that 360px*640

Comment: Edit your question to include your code, using the tools to format it correctly

Comment: Edit your question to include your code, using the tools to format it correctly

Comment: Please do reflect so far worked code in Fiddle or place it below

Comment: `max-device-*` and `min-device-*` are deprecated. Use `max-*` and `min-*` instead

Comment: @r.anand143 your mediaqueries are wrong. You need to analize first the resolutions and think what is your requirement, instead of setting random values to see if it's working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
@media only screen 
  and (min-width: 320px)
  and (max-width: 360px) 
  and (orientation: portrait) {
  // 360px width goes here
}

@media only screen 
  and (max-width: 320px) 
  and (orientation: portrait) {
  // 320px width goes here
}
```

Comment: `max-device-*` and `min-device-*` are deprecated. Use `max-*` and `min-*` instead

Comment: 320 is width and 480 is height, so why is all `max-width` and `min-width`?